# Этимология слова "суппорт"

Tags: этимология

В каких значениях употребляется слово "суппорт" в русском языке? Прошу дать объяснение.

Answer (score 1):

СУппорт (англ. и франц. support, от позднелат. supporto — поддерживаю), узел, предназначенный для крепления и перемещения (при помощи механизма или вручную) инструмента, например в металлорежущих станках. (БСЭ)

СУ́ППОРТ, -а, м. (спец.). Подвижное приспособление для укрепления режущего инструмента или изделия в металлорежущих станках. (Ожегов)

СУППО́РТ, СУПО́РТ (франц. support, от ср.-лат. supporta — "подпорка") — в архитектуре — поддерживающая конструкция: карниз, кронштейн, консоль. В России XVIII—XIX вв. использовали терминологическую форму "супорт", чаще всего подразумевая большие волюты, выполняющие функцию поддерживания выступающих частей здания, например балкона (Словарь изобразительных искусств)

Интересно, что это слово как архитектурный термин даётся с другим ударением.

Comment: >>>Интересно, что это слово как архитектурный термин даётся с другим ударением. 

В архитектуре термины сплошь французские да италианские. А сУпорт - англицизм.

Comment: Нет, не англицизм. По-английски *support* звучит как *съпОт*, и первая гласная там schwa, а вторая — ударная.

Comment: *По-английски support звучит как съпОт* - во первых, Ваша транскрипция уж очень вольная, а во-вторых, фонетические отличия никак не мешают словам быть заимствованными. И англицизмами - в т. ч.

Comment: Транскрипция вольная? Даже не знаю, как это понимать... :( S + schwa (которую я счёл соответствующей русскому звуку, обозначаемому Ъ обычно) + P + ɔ (ударное) + T.